# Section 179 and Closing LLC

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, assets, depreciation

I closed my LLC 2016 (sole, no employees), can I take section 179 tax deductions in the 2016 return?

Do I need to recapture my previous section 179 deductions?

Comment: The answer from my CPA friend on the first question is "Yes". I didn't post an answer because I have no web sources.